# How to resolve org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

I have the following data class:

```
package gulfnet.tts.inthanon.data.product.datadomain;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import lombok.Data;


@Data
public class CommunityItemRecord{

    private String communityId; 
    private String itemId; 
    private ZonedDateTime publicStartDt; 
    private ZonedDateTime publicEndDt; 
    private ZonedDateTime handleEndDt; 
    private String makerCommunityId; 
    private Integer makerApprovalFlg; 
    private String makerApprovalUserId; 

    private ZonedDateTime insDttm; 
    private String insUserId; 
    private ZonedDateTime upDttm; 
    private String upUserId; 

}
```

And the mapper is defined like below:

```
<insert id="insertCommunityItemList" parameterType='list'>
        INSERT ALL
            <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
                     INSERT INTO product.m_community_item (
                        community_id,
                        item_id,
                        public_start_dt,
                        public_end_dt,
                        handle_end_dt,
                        maker_community_id,
                        maker_approval_flg,
                        maker_approval_user_id,
                        ins_user_id,
                        up_user_id
                    ) VALUES (
                        #{element.communityId},
                        #{element.itemId},
                        #{element.publicStartDt},
                        #{element.publicEndDt},
                        #{element.handleEndDt},
                        #{element.makerCommunityId},
                        #{element.makerApprovalFlg},
                        #{element.makerApprovalUserId},
                        #{element.insUserId},
                        #{element.insUserId}
                    )
                on conflict on constraint m_community_item_pk
                do update set
                        public_start_dt = #{element.publicStartDt},
                        public_end_dt = #{element.publicEndDt},
                        up_dttm = current_timestamp,
                        up_user_id = #{element.insUserId}
            </foreach>  
    </insert>
```

And the mapper method is like below:

```
public void insertCommunityItemList(java.util.ArrayList<CommunityItemRecord> communityItemRecordList);
```

I am getting the following error:

> exception=org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   gulfnet.tts.inthanon.data.product.mapper.CatalogMapper.insertCommunityItemList
>   (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch
>   entry 0 INSERT ALL was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the
>   cause. ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "ALL"   Position: 8

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT ALL` is invalid for Postgres. I don't know MyBatis, but probably something like the following is needed:

```
<insert id="insertCommunityItemList" parameterType='list'>
  INSERT INTO product.m_community_item (
          community_id,
          item_id,
          public_start_dt,
          public_end_dt,
          handle_end_dt,
          maker_community_id,
          maker_approval_flg,
          maker_approval_user_id,
          ins_user_id,
          up_user_id)
  VALUES 
  <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
    (
        #{element.communityId},
        #{element.itemId},
        #{element.publicStartDt},
        #{element.publicEndDt},
        #{element.handleEndDt},
        #{element.makerCommunityId},
        #{element.makerApprovalFlg},
        #{element.makerApprovalUserId},
        #{element.insUserId},
        #{element.insUserId}
    )
  </foreach>
  on conflict on constraint m_community_item_pk
  do update set
      public_start_dt = excluded.public_start_dt,
      public_end_dt = excluded.public_end_dt,
      up_dttm = current_timestamp,
      up_user_id = excluded.public_end_dt
</insert>
```

The foreach loop should only iterate over the actual rows. The `INSERT INTO` and `on conflict` parts must only appear once.

Comment: @I.Ahmed, this must be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java Iterator to iterator your communityItemRecordList and insert into database one by one.

```
//java
communityItemRecordList.forEach(c -> {
    mapperInstance.insert(c);
});
//mapper xml
<insert id="insert">
    ....
</insert>
```

I don't think using dynamic SQL in this demo is appropriate.

I just used foreach element and tested successfully. Code:

```
//java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SmsContentDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private SmsContentDao smsContentDao;

    @Test
    public void insertList() {
        List<SmsContentDO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        SmsContentDO item = SmsContentDO.builder().name("john").company("abc").job("farmer").build();
        list.add(item);
        item = SmsContentDO.builder().name("tom").company("nba").job("player").build();
        list.add(item);
        int rows = smsContentDao.insertList(list);
        System.out.println(rows);//2
    }
}
//mapper interface
int insertList(List<SmsContentDO> list);
//mapper xml, the dialect of mysql 
<!-- int insertList(List<SmsContentDO> list);-->
    <insert id="insertList">
        insert into
            sms_content (`name`,`company`,`job`)
        values
        <foreach collection="list" item="item" separator=",">
            (#{item.name},#{item.company},#{item.job})
        </foreach>
    </insert>
```

Comment: One by one will create performance issue, if you want to insert 10000 items

Comment: OK.If i use <foreach> element,i will use like below.```<insert id="">insert into ... values <foreach item="item" collection="list" separator=",">(#{item.a},#{item.b})</foreach></insert>```.This is mysql grammar,hope it could help you